# Implementation of vector space model in java

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

Does anyone tell me how to transform the text documents to vectors by the bag-of-words concepts? And how to implement vector space model in java? Actually, i have preprocessed the text data set upto stemming process and now i have to transform those text documents into vectorized model using the bag-of-words concept.Does anyone help me? How to implement this in java?

Answer (score 0):

Build a dictionary.

You assign every word a unique integer index, which is the dimension in the VSM.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer, because i'm beginner. Can you?

Comment: There is not much more to say, it's really straightforward.